# "I am open to become" or "I am open to becoming"

Tags: grammar

"I am open to become more open-minded about this."

"I am open to becoming more open-minded about this."

Are they both grammatically correct? What's the difference in meaning.

Answer (score 1):

The second sentence (open to becom**ing**) is correct. The phrase "open to [something]" takes a noun or gerund (which is a "*nounal* verb"): *open to suggestions*, *open to change*, *open to being corrected*.

The first sentence has no real meaning because it is not grammatically correct, though a person hearing the sentence would probably interpret it as it was intended.